# Checking If Array Is Ascending Using Recursion

Tags: arrays, c, recursion

I have learned recursion just recently and I was met with a question that I **HAVE** to approach it using recursion which says something like this, I need a function that takes an array and it's size using user input and checks if the array is ascending and if it is it returns 1 and if not it returns 0, now I know doing it without recursion is way easier but I had to do it with recursion, i tried different approaches to my base case and my `if-else` conditions and it didn't work out well I tried something like  `Array[Index] >= Array[Index-1]` , and tried some other stuff alongside , but for some reason it just won't work and keeps giving me that it's descending

Here is what I tried: I have my main in which user inputs array and size(aka index here) and then calling this recursive function to try and see if it's ascending, now I assumed I'm starting from the most left of the array and go down gradually and check but it doesn't work, anyone got some tips on what's happening here?

```
int CheckIfAscending(int* Array, int Index)
{
    if (Index < 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (Array[Index] > Array[Index - 1])
    {
        return CheckIfAscending(Array, Index - 1);
    }
    if (Array[Index] < Array[Index - 1])
    {
        return 0;
    }     
}
```

Comment: What do you return in case `Array[Index] == Array[Index - 1]`?

Comment: UB when `Index` is `0`.

Comment: Also UB if `Index` is the size of the array (with `int a[10];`, the elements are `a[0]` to `a[9]` inclusive).

Comment: Your second `if` can be replaced with `else { return 0; }` (ignoring UB) for (arguably) better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious vulnerability of your code is the lack of defined behaviour for arrays which can have the same value occur in two consecutive entries.
Because what do you return in case `Array[Index] == Array[Index - 1]`?
Your code does not specify, it does not have any `return` statement for that case.

You need to decide whether you want strictly ascending, i.e. two identical values are a failure, or only ascending, i.e. they are fine.

For strictly ascending do this

```
if (Array[Index] > Array[Index - 1])
{
    return CheckIfAscending(Array, Index - 1);
} else
{
    return 0;
}
```

otherwise use `>=`.

You also need to fix the first condition `if (Index < 0)`, because for index 0 (actually size I think...) you need to already answer directly, otherwise `Index - 1` is meaningless. So, use `Index <= 0` instead.

Comment: I Tried this way and stricted it to ascending or equal like so : https://imgur.com/a/dClsSOt , however it keeps returning the value of 0 (Descending)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in your question, containing the initially shown code, the input you provide (or even better skip inputting and work with an array which is initialised to hard-coded values) to provoke the behaviour you describe.